# multi-observed features

Tags: regression, machine-learning-model, categorical-data

I am working on a ML model where individual features may have a highly variable number of observed values.
The model will predict a continuous variable so I am planning to use a Regressor.

More precisely, I am dealing with roughly 40 features some of which are categorical and some are continuous.  All the features can have a variable number of observed values for each target value in the training set.  Are there any models that natively handle a variable # of observations per feature or do I need to select one value per feature in some manner (e.g. mean, first observed, etc.)?

Comment: [multiple instance learning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_instance_learning)